# How to uninstall Nginx (and reinstall it) under plesk?

Tags: nginx, debian, apt, plesk, debian-buster

I rent a VPS from OVH  without Plesk License but they installed Plesk anyway against my consent. This lead to a lot of problems. I had an hard time for everything, installing the last version of Python 3, have the right version of `mod_wsgi` or upgrade to Debian Buster...

Now, I want to migrate from Apache to Nginx and it's a mess. I tought first I had to install Nginx myself but because of Plesk, it was already installed. I d'like to remove it but my `apt` command is stuck in a kind of inter-dependency problem hard to solve.

When I do:

```
apt-get remove nginx
```

Result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-http-echo : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-http-geoip : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-mail : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnginx-mod-stream : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I Try

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

Result:

```
...
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.14.2-2+deb10u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.14.2-2+deb10u1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.14.2-2+deb10u1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/default/nginx', which is also in package sw-nginx 1.16.1.3-debian8.0.19111813
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Preparing to unpack .../nginx-full_1.14.2-2+deb10u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-full (1.14.2-2+deb10u1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-full_1.14.2-2+deb10u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/nginx', which is also in package sw-nginx 1.16.1.3-debian8.0.19111813
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
...
```

Same result with `sudo apt-get  install -f nginx-common nginx-full`

Note that:

```
ls /etc/default/nginx
ls: cannot access '/etc/default/nginx': No such file or directory
```

Because I moved it, so there is nothing to overwrite :/

I tried to remove those package with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove libnginx* --purge
```

It gives:

```
Package 'libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnginx-mod-http-fancyindex' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnginx-mod-http-lua' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnginx-mod-http-ndk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnginx-mod-http-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnginx-mod-http-uploadprogress' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnginx-mod-nchan' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnginx-mod-rtmp' is not installed, so not removed
```

`sudo apt-get autoremove nginx` gives the same result. I'm really stuck with that.

`dpkg -l | grep "libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge"` doesn't return anything.

If I do a search in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` I can"t find thoses Package as well.

I also run:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

but it leads in those type of errors:

```
...
dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-http-echo (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter:
 libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter depends on nginx-common (= 1.14.2-2+deb10u1); however:
  Package nginx-common is not installed
...
```

I want a clean installation of Nginx, the one I've is broken and I would like to be able to update it when I want easily. What can I do ?

Comment: Hi, plesk related questions are off-topic for serverfault but I would guess from the error message that you'd have to get rid of 'sw-nginx', e.g. `apt purge sw-nginx`

Comment: yes that what I just do. I also removed the packages with `dpkg --remove`. I should ask on super user maybe ? It sometimes hard to guess what server fault is about ^^